# How to go to the same custom page twice from two different custom pages in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

You can skip pages based on condition. However, how can you go to the same user page from two different user pages?

```pascal
UserPage1 := CreateCustomPage(
  UserPageA.ID,
  'Title 1',
  'Sub Title 1'
);            
UserPage1.OnNextButtonClick := @UserPage1NextButtonClick;

UserPage2 := CreateCustomPage(
  UserPageB.ID,
  'Title 2',
  'Sub Title 2'
);            
UserPage2.OnNextButtonClick := @UserPage2NextButtonClick;

UserPage3 := CreateCustomPage(
  UserPage1.ID,
  'Title 3',
  'Sub Title 3'
);            
UserPage3.OnNextButtonClick := @UserPage3NextButtonClick;
```

In the above code, `UserPage1` and `UserPage2` needs to show the `UserPage3` when the *Next* button is clicked. That means that the overall order of the pages should be `UserPageA`, `UserPage1`, `UserPage3`, `UserPageB`, `UserPage2` and again `UserPage3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to display the same page twice.

Implement the page twice. Copy over the data entered by the user between the two instances on the *Back*/*Next* button clicks.